# Start InfluxDB v2 in a docker container with a conf-file on Windows 10

Tags: docker, influxdb

I'm new to docker and also influx so I guess this question is in general a trivial one.

Because there don't exist an influxdb v2 for Windows yet I'm using the turnaround via docker with the official image quay.io/influxdb/influxdb:v2.0.3

On [this installation guide](https://www.open-plant.com/knowledge-base/how-to-install-influxdb-docker-for-windows-10/) it is explained how to start influxdb with an additional conf-file on Windows 10, but with another docker image and following command:

```
docker run -p 8086:8086 -v C:/ProgramData/InfluxDB:/var/lib/influxdb influxdb -config /var/lib/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```

I thought it's simple to adapt this guide and only replace the image.
According to my understanding I would have to use the following command to start my container, if my conf-file lies in C:/ProgrammData/InfluxDB

```
docker run --name influxv2 -p 8086:8086 -v C:/ProgrammData/InfluxDB:/var/lib/influxdb quay.io/influxdb/influxdb:v2.0.3 -config /var/lib/influxdb/influxdb.conf
```

With this command I always get the error

> Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'c' in -config

Unfortunately I don't now how to fix the command and hope for a simple solution. Thank's a lot.

Comment: Official docker image for influxdb 2 does not exist also, it is not yet generally available.
Here it is clearly written to use 1.8 for both production and development: https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb/

Comment: Ah thank's for the hint. You're right the term "official" here is misleading. What I mean is the docker image on the influx site https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads/ 
Unfortunately it's not my choice to use 1.8 so it would be helpful if there is a solution for v2.0.3